# Cut Out Polygon Layer out of Polygon

Tags: html, css, wordpress

everyone,

I would like to cut out a polygon so you can see the background.
I've already achieved this with a radiant gradient, but I don't want to cut out a circle but the polygon itself, so that it has a background color but is cut out in the middle.
Here is a small example of what it should look like in the end:

[image]

The background should therefore be transparent because a background image is also installed.

Here is the code I already have:
HTML:

```
<div class="main-hexaconb first-level" style="--r: 0.9; --mv: -1px; --v: 0.5; --s: 200px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hexagon hexagons-first-level">
            <div class="hexagon-frontend-middle">       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-hexaconb {
    display: flex;
    --s: 100px;
    --r: 1;
    --h: 0.25;
    --v: 0.35;
    --hc: calc(clamp(0, var(--h), 0.5) * var(--s));
    --vc: calc(clamp(0, var(--v), 0.5) * var(--s) * var(--r));
    --mv: 4px;
    --mh: calc(var(--mv) + (var(--s) - 2*var(--hc))/2);
    --f: calc(2*var(--s)*var(--r) + 4*var(--mv) - 2*var(--vc) - 2px);
}

.container div {
    width: var(--s);
    margin: var(--mv) var(--mh);
    height: calc(var(--s) * var(--r));
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: initial;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(var(--hc) 0, calc(100% - var(--hc)) 0, 100% var(--vc), 100% calc(100% - var(--vc)), calc(100% - var(--hc)) 100%, var(--hc) 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--vc)), 0 var(--vc));
    clip-path: polygon(var(--hc) 0, calc(100% - var(--hc)) 0, 100% var(--vc), 100% calc(100% - var(--vc)), calc(100% - var(--hc)) 100%, var(--hc) 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--vc)), 0 var(--vc));
    margin-bottom: calc(var(--mv) - var(--vc));
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.container::before {
    content: "";
    width: calc(var(--s) / 2 + var(--mh));
    float: left;
    height: 135%;
    shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0 calc(var(--f) - 2px), #000 0 var(--f));
}

.container div:not(.hexagon-frontend-middle)>*:not(.hexaconb-img) {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: var(--s);
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: calc(var(--s) - 60px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .hexagon-frontend-middle> :not(.hexaconb-img) {
    position: relative;
    max-width: var(--s);
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: calc(var(--s) - 60px);
    word-break: break-word;
}


.hexagon:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: inherit;
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: inherit;
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-frontend-middle {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle 30px at calc(100% - 101px) calc(100% - 90px), transparent 80px, white 0px);
    max-height: unset !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

This CSS currently gives me a runic clipped circle, but I want a polygon clipped circle. Here's an example:

CSS-Line

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle 30px at calc(100% - 101px) calc(100% - 90px), transparent 80px, white 0px);
```

Frontend at the moment:

[image]

Comment: https://css-generators.com/polygon-shape/

Comment: @TemaniAfif As I was reading the question, I though to myself this is a question for Temani Afif.